# When using let in a for loop initialization, why isn't the let variable avaiable in the enclosing scope?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

This has always been a lingering question for me: If block scopes are created when a `let` or `const` identifier is enclosed within curly brackets, then how is the `let` identifier in the initialization statement of a `for` loop not available in the enclosing scope but is instead available inside the curly brackets of the `for` loop?

```js
(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   console.log(i) // logs current value of i
  }
  console.log(i) // referenceError
})()
```

Comment: The `for` loop is considered its own block scope. Syntax wise the variable itself is outside of the curly brackets, but it helps to imagine it as `{ for(...) do stuff }`

Comment: That's the basic mental model I've been using to understand this behavior, but it seems at odds with the way `let` and `const` are supposed to work in relation to curly brackets. 

Are there other things in the language that behave similarly as `for` in this respect?

Comment: Any of your loops (for of/in, switch, etc.) are block scoped, but syntactically speaking, it'd even be the same for functions. Your parameters are technically outside of the functions 'curly brackets', but still only scoped to that function. That's where the variable initialization occurs. The keyword `for` or `function` is where that scope starts.

Comment: The comparison to how function arguments are handled makes a lot of sense. Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how things work. A variable declared at the top of a `for` loop like that is only visible inside the current iteration's `for` block. You can think of it a bit like this:

```
<loop> {
  let i = getCount();
  console.log(i) // logs current value of i
}
```

where `getCount` runs the logic that increments `i`.

Variables declared with `let` are block-scoped - it wouldn't make sense for `i` to be referenceable outside. If the `i` *was* visible outside of the `for`, what would you expect its value to be? You already have a separate `i` binding for every iteration of the loop. It wouldn't make sense to somewhat-arbitrarily pick one of those bindings to be visible outside.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Are there any other aspect of JS that behave similarly to this?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a local variable in the `for` loop and not outside it. If you had declared it outside the loop, you could access it correctly.

```js
(function() {
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   console.log(i);
  }
  console.log(i);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your syntax, you could use `var`.

```
(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    console.log(i); 
    // this should work.
})()
```

Otherwise, a variable declared with `let` or `const` has what's called *Block Scope* meaning that it's only visible inside the curly braces it was defined in. That's essentially the fundamental difference between `let` and `var`. A variable declared with `var` has *Function Scope* (It's visible throughout the function, even before it's lexical definition, it's value will just be `undefined`)

```
(function() {
    console.log(i); // undefined
    var i = 10;
    console.log(i); // 10
 })();
```

But the example above will only work if there is no `"use strict"` anywhere.

Comment: > it's only visible inside the curly braces it was defined in

That's precisely why I'm confused. The `let` is declared within the curly brackets of the enclosing function, not that of the for loop itself.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, in the case of `for` loops, the declaration is counted as part of the block. Hope that helps